# Serving Angular Build files from Express

Tags: node.js, angular

I currently have a barebones angular application, where I am trying to serve the bundled files from build of my angular client app through my express server.

I am using ng-build to build the angular code and copy the contents of the dist folder into the dist folder of my server. It looks like the following

[image]

When I bootup the server, I can render the index.html but see the following in my console

```
GET /inline.bundle.js.map 404 8.875 ms - 159
GET /polyfills.bundle.js.map 404 3.486 ms - 162
GET /styles.bundle.js.map 404 2.860 ms - 159
GET /vendor.bundle.js.map 404 2.695 ms - 159
GET /main.bundle.js.map 404 2.956 ms - 157
```

To hook up the client to server, I have the following in **app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { routing } from './app.routing';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {QueuedService} from "./queued.service";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue:'/'}, QueuedService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My **queued.service.ts** has the following

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class QueuedService {
  host:string = "http://localhost:8080";

  constructor(private http: Http){}

}
```

At the moment, I am not sure if I am bridging the client and server properly.

**EDITED**

Here is my **index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Queued Application</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

  <style>
    #signUp{
      margin-right: 30px;
    }
    #searchRestaurants{
      padding-left: 250px;
      padding-top: 50px;
    }

    #showRestaurantsList{
      display: none;
      margin-top: 20px;
    }

    #reservationPage{
      display: none;
      margin-top: 20px;
    }

    #navBar{
      min-height: 65px;
      background-color: #333;
    }

    body{
      background-color: aliceblue;
    }

    #appName{
      color: white;
      font-size: 20px;
      font-family: Helvetica;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also here is my express server

```
export class Server {

    public app: express.Application;
    public RestaurantList: RestaurantListModel;

    /**
     * Bootstrap the application.
     *
     * @class Server
     * @method bootstrap
     * @static
     * @return {ng.auto.IInjectorService} Returns the newly created injector for this app.
     */
    public static bootstrap(): Server {
        return new Server();
    }

    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @class Server
     * @constructor
     */
    constructor() {
        //create expressjs application
        this.app = express();

        //add routes
        this.routes();

        //configure application
        this.config();

        this.RestaurantList = new RestaurantListModel();

        //add api
        this.api();

    }

    /**
     * Create REST API routes
     *
     * @class Server
     * @method api
     */
    public api() {
        //empty for now
    }

    /**
     * Configure application
     *
     * @class Server
     * @method config
     */
    private config() : void {
        //add static paths
        // this.app.use('/', express.static(__dirname+'/dist/public'));

        //use logger middlware
        this.app.use(logger("dev"));

        //use json form parser middlware
        this.app.use(bodyParser.json());

        //use query string parser middlware
        this.app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
            extended: true
        }));

        //use cookie parker middleware middlware
        this.app.use(cookieParser("SECRET_GOES_HERE"));

        //use override middlware
        this.app.use(methodOverride());


        //catch 404 and forward to error handler
        this.app.use(function(err: any, req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction) {
            err.status = 404;
            next(err);
        });

        //error handling
        this.app.use(errorHandler());
    }

    /**
     * Create router
     *
     * @class Server
     * @method api
     */
    public routes() {
        let router: express.Router;
        router = express.Router();

        //IndexRoute
        /*
        router.post('/queued/restaurantList', (req, res) =>{
            let jsonObj = req.body;
            console.log(jsonObj);
        });*/

        router.get('/queued/restaurantList',(req, res) => {
            console.log('List of the restaurants');
            this.RestaurantList.getAllItems(res);
        });


        //use router middleware
        this.app.use('/',router);
        this.app.use(express.static(__dirname));

    }
}
```

Comment: show us ur index.html baseHref and your express setup in the serve

Comment: @Milad edited the OP as per requested